# OSGI Classloading & Object Sharing

Tags: java, osgi, classloader

Ok. So I know that a class instantiated with ClassloaderA can not be passed directly to ClassloaderB because in the JVM's eyes, the "class" of the object will be different in a different classloader.

I also know that Serializing the object to send it to ClassloaderB will be very slow and I can't see OSGi containers using this method. If I have a bundleA which exports a service to BundleB (which imports the service) and a method "serviceMethod()" is called which returns an ObjectA, how is ObjectA passed from BundleA to BundleB?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you import the same package in two bundles then normally both are wired to the same classloader for this package.
Lets assume we have bundle A providing the service interface and associated classes, bundle B providing the service with an internal service impl and bundle C using the service.

Bundle B will import the service interface and other packages with classes of the service. So if it does new on a class from an imported package then it will trigger his own classloader (B) to load the class. This classloader will then delegate to classloader A as the package is imported. So effectively service classes will loaded by classloader A.

The same then applies to bundle C as the common classes are also imported loading will be delegated to classloader A. So both bundles will be able to communicate using the service interface and imported classes.

Btw. you can even transport objects unknown to bundle C. For example bundle B could create a private class and return it in the service as "Object". Then bundle C could still work with the class and use reflection on it. So no need for marshalling.

The only case where OSGi classloading can go wrong is if for example bundle C embeds the service interface jar A. Then these packages will be loaded with classloader C. So they will be different from the ones known to bundle B. So stay away from embedding if possible.

Comment: One of the driving forces behind my asking this question was spending a whole afternoon trying to figure out why Karaf was telling me my ActiveMQConnectionFactory couldn't be cast to a ConnectionFactory. To get up and running quickly, I built an uber-bundle including ALL of the dependencies I needed to run ActiveMQ... unfortunately, it also included the javax.jms.ConnectionFactory class. Because it was being supplied in the ActiveMQ jar but the bundle with the instance of the ActiveMQConnectionFactory was using my wrapped javax.jms bundle, it saw them as two different classes.

Comment: Yes .. that happens in many cases when using the uber bundle aproach. Fortunately in your case it is easy. ActiveMQ is already available as a karaf feature. Try feature:chooseurl activemq 5.9.0 . You can then install the activemq features. I am using this in one of my tutorials: http://liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/2012/01/03/Karaf+Tutorial+Part+5+-+Running+Apache+Camel+integrations+in+OSGi

Answer (score 0):

The classloader associated with `BundleB` is wired to load classes from `BundleA` because `BundleA` is defined as a dependency. Thus `BundleB` has access to the classes of objects returned from `BundleA`.

See:

- http://codescale.wordpress.com/2009/05/22/basics-about-osgi-classloading/
- http://www.slideshare.net/martinlippert/classloading-and-type-visibility-in-osgi-presentation

Comment: I totally understand that "classes" can be loaded and instantiated- This part makes sense because you are essentially just pulling in packages from another bundle. The case I described is different. I'm talking about a service that BundleA holds. The service itself is exported and still lives in BundleA. When BundleB asks BundleA to cal the method "serviceMethod()" on and takes the object returned, how does that object make its way to BundleB?

Comment: A "service" must have an interface, right? That interface must be available to both bundles doesn't it? So that means the classes that make up that service interface are loaded by both classloaders.

Comment: I thought a class in two different classloaders was looked at differently. Is it because both classloaders point to the same jar file that they are seen as the same class?

Comment: I'm looking @ the java classloading basics. I'm seeing this: "It is important to keep this hash table around since you must return the same class object reference for the same class name every time you are asked for it. Otherwise the system will believe there are two different classes with the same name and will throw a ClassCastException whenever you assign an object reference between them. "

My guess is that OSGI's bundle class loaders use that same object reference when exporting/importing?

Comment: Classloaders have hierarchies. Common dependencies are put at the bottom of the tree. See these excellent slides for details http://www.slideshare.net/martinlippert/classloading-and-type-visibility-in-osgi-presentation

Comment: Thanks! This tells me everything. I was missing the hierarchy part. I thought the bundle classloaders were "completely" isolated. Thanks for your responses!